# Electrical part question

Tags: identification, adapter, wall-wart

Does anyone knows the name of the part that connects with this power adapters cable?

[image]

Comment: barrel jack or coaxial power jack/socket

Comment: If the barrel jack we would need the adapter model number anyways. It is likely a 5.5mm OD, 2.5 ID or 5.5 OD, 2.1 ID style if I had to guess.

Comment: CD player, keyboard, cell-phone etc...

Comment: At the *other* end (neither end was specified), the part that connects with it would be called an "electrical outlet", or "single receptacle", or "duplex receptacle".

Answer (score 4):

There are a few names for these type of connectors:

- [DC Connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_connector)
- DC Power Jack/Plug
- Barrel Power Jack/Plug
- Coaxial (or Co-Ax) Power Jack/Plug

Examples of parts you can get for making your own adapter cords or soldering to a PCB:

**DC Power Jack:**

[image: DC Power Jack]

**DC Power Plug:**

[image: DC Power Plug]

Regarding the size of these connectors, this excerpt from Wikipedia says it best:

> The most common plugs are 5.5 mm (0.22 in) in outside diameter (OD) and 9.5 mm (0.37 in) in length. Two pin sizes are common in the jacks for this size plug body, 2.1 mm (0.083 in) and 2.5 mm (0.098 in), and the plugs should ideally match. Generic plugs are often named for the pin diameter they are designed to take.
>
> [...] The 'tip' (i.e., the inner conductor) usually carries the positive (+) pole.

You can find these at online electronics vendors ([DigiKey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/barrel-power-connectors/1443096), [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/Connectors/Power-Connectors/DC-Power-Connectors/_/N-axitt/) and [All Electronics](http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/category/198/connectors-dc-power-coax/1.html)) as well as [Radio Shack](http://www.radioshack.com/home/index.jsp) if you happen to have one nearby.